# addTarget:action:forControlEvents: ignored when interacting with separate UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm somewhat new to iOS programming

I have some code (abridged) that looks like the following

```
UIView *someSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
[self addSubView:someSubView];
[someSubView addTarget:self action:@selector(_handleTapOnView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

_tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleTap:)];
_tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Unfortunately the gesture recognizer triggers and my views addTarget call does not. I've tried commenting out the gesture recognizer code and it works, so I know its not the call to addTarget on the subview.

I solved this initially by using the gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: and doing a hit test for the sub view, but I feel like I'm missing some fundamental understanding here that wouldn't require me adding a manual hit test.

Its important to note that I don't want the code in the _handleTap in the _tapGestureRecognizer to execute when I have tapped on my subview.

Any guidance here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
_tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

otherwise the gesture recogniser will intercept the touches and will not forward them further (in other words, the gesture recogniser gets the touch, handles it, and since it cancel it, no other object gets the touch). By not cancelling, the touch is forwarded for any other object (recognisers or views) to handle it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This works, but it has the side-effect of still triggering the _tapGestureRecognizer. I should have added to my original question that I don't want the tapGestureRecognizer to trigger as I feel like the action of my subview should get triggered first and not forward on the event. Does that make sense? I have modified my question to address this extra requirement.